# Check whether certain array keys are given or not

Tags: php, arrays, function, arguments, associative-array

I'm writing some kind of a function that accepts an associative array as an argument.

This array can be:

1. Empty
2. Has only one element. With key either `pageParam` or `wrapperClass`.
3. Has two elements. Must be keyed with `pageParam` and `wrapperClass`.

Now i've written these checks to ensure that:

1. The array is not more than 2 elements.
2. The array does not have any elements other than `pageParam` and `wrapperClass`

The problem is, My second check is not working properly. Here's my code :

```
public function init_paginator(array $parameters = array())
{
    if(!empty($parameters))
    {
            // This check works
        if(count($parameters) > 2)
        {
            throw new \Exception("Paginator only accepts 2 elements in array: pageParam and wrapperClass.");
        }

            // This check does not work, even if its condition is satisfied 
        if(!in_array(array_keys($parameters), array('pageParam', 'wrapperClass')))
        {
            throw new \Exception("Paginator only accepts 2 elements in array: pageParam and wrapperClass.");    
        }

        // Code..
    }

}
```

The exception in the second check is always thrown if i entered the array argument like :

1. `array("dummyKey"=>"dummyValue")`
2. `array("dummyKey1"=>"dummyValue1", "dummyKey2"=>"dummyValue2")`
3. `array("pageParam"=>"test")` Or `array("wrapperClass"=>"wrapper_class")`
4. `array("pageParam"=>"test", "wrapperClass"=>"wrapper_class")`

The last two inputs is what puzzles me! Why the exception is thrown despite that my arguments are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second check looks for the value `array_keys($parameters)` inside `array('pageParam', 'wrapperClass')`. It compares an array of strings with two string values.

What you want is the keys of `$parameters` to be equal to the values of `array('pageParam', 'wrapperClass')`, thus:

```
array_keys($parameters) === array('pageParam', 'wrapperClass');
```

For arrays, the `===` operator evaluates to TRUE if [both arrays have the same key/value pairs in the same order and of the same types](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php). If you don't care about order, you can use `==`.

By the way, this check renders the first one useless.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the way you use `in_array`

It'll never work because it keeps matching an array `array_keys($parameters)` to strings within another array `array('pageParam', 'wrapperClass')`

So, it keeps returning `false`

See [PHP: in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

Using `array( array('pageParam', 'wrapperClass'), array('pageParam'), array('wrapperClass'), array())` as second parameter for `in_array` might work.

Answer (score 1):

The doc aren't as descriptive as they should be, but the intent with the two arrays as args is that the needle is an array and the haystack is an array of arrays (multi-dimensional) that may contain the needle array.  I'm headed out so will look again later, but maybe this as an alternative:

```
if(count(array_diff_key(array_keys(array('pageParam', 'wrapperClass')), $parameters)) > 1) {
    //exception
}
```